# Return variable name associated with maximum value Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables

I would like to return the maximum value between two, but return the variable that is assigned to that number...not the number itself.

```
A = 3

B = 7

max(A,B)

    7
```

Instead, I would like to return

```
'B'
```

I am sorry if this is an obvious question. I just have not found an answer online.

Comment: Why not just return the maximum value?

Comment: I do. It says here that I return 7 in this case... I want to return "B" instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if B >= A
  Bigvar='B';
else
  Bigvar='A';
end
```

But I should say that in general if you need to know a variable name the way you describe then there are probably better ways of structuring your code. That's why it doesn't come up when you search.

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you. I ended up doing what you wrote. Thank you. I also agree with you. I am just quickly scripting something but I will keep your advice in mind for more involved projects.